# Wis/Int classes with strong AoE stunning powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

Context: I'm planning on playing a Deva Wis/Int Wizard who takes Soul of the World at Epic and grabs Royal Command of Asmodeus via Past Life Tiefling, and I was wondering, what class would have the best AoE stunning powers for taking advantage of Royal Command? (that I would grab using Soul of the World's 24th level feature.)

Answer (score 3):

### Probably go with Invoker

AoE Stun is extremely powerful, so even at the highest levels it's pretty uncommon, but you'll want to look at Controller classes. As a Wizard, you already have access to one of the few. However, Invokers seem to have the biggest variety of options, letting you pack all the more of them at once.

#### Wizard

**Prismatic Spray - Wizard Level 25 Daily**

A friendly close <s>burst</s> blast 5 that attacks all three non-AC defenses, applying different effects for each defense of the target you hit. If you hit Will, the target is save-ends stunned. Hitting the other defenses adds on a good amount of damage and debilitating effects. The biggest drawback to this power is its Poison keyword.

#### Psion

Unfortunately, while Psions get an "encounter" AoE stun at level 27, you can't get it for yourself due to the fact that they're augmentable at-will attacks instead of normal encounter attacks.

**Mind Blast - Psion Level 9 Daily**

No damage and unfriendly, but still a close blast 5 save-ends stun that you can grab immediately at level 24, and even carry both if you want.

#### Invoker

While many of their powers self-inflict daze, you can mitigate that quite a bit if you're carrying Superior Will. They're packing some good options, though they're a Wis class, so unless you started with your Int and Wis equal, they'll be less accurate than other options.

**Silent Malediction - Invoker Level 1 Daily**

As far down as level 1, Invokers are getting an AoE stun. Not that it really matters to you since you're level 24 already anyway, but it's still pretty surprising. In any case, this is an unfriendly close blast 3 that does some damage and a stun (save ends). It's even Thunder already for size-boosting convenience. Self-daze.

**Word of Bewilderment - Invoker Level 23 Encounter**

That's right, an encounter power (that you can actually use). Unfriendly close burst 2. Only lasts a round instead of save ends, but still, it's an encounter power. Self-daze.

**Compel Action - Invoker Level 27 Encounter**

Of course, you can always skip all that jumping through hoops of finding stunning powers and just grab an AoE dominate instead! Unfriendly close blast 5 that doesn't do any damage, but just straight-up dominates everything it hits for a round, and the only negative effect you get is granting CA for a round.

**Word of the Gods - Invoker Level 29 Daily**

And speaking of AoE dominate, here's a (save ends) one on a daily! Friendly close blast 5, and this one even packs some damage on a miss or if they save. Even better, it doesn't even have any backlash to it.